# How to check a String for characters NOT to be included in C#

Tags: c#, string

So I have a String like:

```
String myString = "AAAaAAA";
```

I want to check the String if it contains ANY characters that are not "A"

How can I do this? my previous code is:

```
 Regex myChecker = new Regex("[^A.$]$");
     if (checkForIncluded.IsMatch(myString))
     {
       //Do some Stuff
     }
```

Is there any other way to do it? The code above does not detect the small a. But when I use a different String with only characters that are not "A" it works. Thank you!

Comment: Is your input string subject to localization i.e. non english languages? If yes, Then you should use `CultureInfo` to compare the non-desirable character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 var allowedChars = new List<char>() { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
 var myString = "abcA";
 var result = myString.Any(c => !allowedChars.Contains(c));
 if (result) {
    // myString contains something not in allowed chars
 }
```

or even like this:

```
if (myString.Except(allowedChars).Any()) {
   // ...
}
```

allowedChars can be any IEnumerable< char >.

Answer (score 2):

```
String myString = "AAAaAAA";
if(myString.Any(x => x != 'A')) {
    // Yep, contains some non-'A' character
}
```

Comment: What if I want to check for other letters in the same string? E.G. String myString ="ABCa"; I want to include the A, the B and the C?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq:

```
String myString = "AAAaAAA";

var result = myString.Where(x=>x != 'A'); // return all character that are not A

if(result.Count() > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Characters exists other than a");
}
```

if you want both cases:

```
String myString = "AAAaAAA";

var result = myString.Where(x=>x != 'A' || x != 'a');
```

or Use `String.Equals()`:

```
var result = myString.Where(x => !String.Equals(x.ToString(), "A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: How about we use CultureInfo to ignore case?

Comment: `.Any` (as in my answer) is the better (and more obvious) choice here -- it is presumably short-circuited to stop evaluation as soon as it can.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check the String if it contains ANY characters that are not
>   "A"

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like;

```
string myString = "AAAaAAA";
bool b = myString.Any(s => !s.Equals('A')); // True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is only trying to match the last character. This should work:

```
var myString = "AAaA";
bool anyNotAs  = Regex.IsMatch(myString, "[^A]", RegexOptions.None);
```